# $2007^{201} + 2019^{201} - 1982^{201} - 2044^{201}$ is divisible by which of the following?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, binomial-theorem

[image]

I reduced it to

$(2013-6)^{201} + (2013+6)^{201} - (2013-31)^{201} - (2013+31)^{201} $

But this way I only get option D. How do I check for the other options. (Multiple correct question)

Comment: Factorise 2013. What do you get?

Comment: 25 is definitely a factor

Comment: $2019=1982+37$ and $2044=2007+37$.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem? The Euler extension of this? Can you deal with divisibility by the small primes involved - $2, 3, 5^2$? What of the larger primes?

Comment: I know how to deal with divisibility of high powers by small numbers using binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$2007^{201}+2019^{201}$ is divisible by $2007+2019=4026=2\cdot2013$ and

$1982^{201}+2044^{201}$ is divisible by $1982+2044=4026=2\cdot2013$.

Thus, our expression is divisible by $2013$.

The expression is an even number, $2019-1982=37$ and $2007-2044=-37$, which says that our expression is divisible by $74$.

Also, $2007-1982=-25$, $2019-2044=-25$, which says that our expression is divisible by $50$ and by $50\cdot37=1850.$